# No se muestran todos los resultados de una consulta en mi JTable

Tags: java, mysql, netbeans

Tengo un código que me busca dentro de un inventario por código de producto y otros parámetros, y sí me busca, el problema es que al buscar, y mostrar los resultados en un `JTable`, sólo me muestra el primer valor que encuentra, descartando el resto, intenté hacer un recorrido con un `for`, pero me tira un error de índice, pueden ayudarme?

Adjunto el código que uso:

```
            if (buscar.equals("Categoria")) {

                con = conexion();

                ps2 = con.prepareStatement("SELECT nombre FROM tblcategoria WHERE nombre = ?");
                ps2.setString(1, txtbuscar.getText());
                rs2 = ps2.executeQuery();
                if (rs2.next()) {
                    String nombre = rs2.getString(1);
                    System.out.println(nombre);
                    ps = con.prepareStatement("SELECT a.idinventario,b.nombre,a.cantidad,c.nombre,a.fecha,b.preciounidad FROM tblinventario a, tblproducto b, tblcategoria c WHERE c.nombre = ?");

                    ps.setString(1, nombre);

                    rs = ps.executeQuery();


                    if (rs.next()) {


                            DefaultTableModel modelo6 = new DefaultTableModel();
                            modelo6.addColumn("ID Inventario");
                            modelo6.addColumn("Nombre del producto");
                            modelo6.addColumn("Cantidad");
                            modelo6.addColumn("Categoría");
                            modelo6.addColumn("Fecha");
                            modelo6.addColumn("Precio unitario");
                            tabla.setModel(modelo6);
                            String data2[] = new String[6];


                            data2[0] = rs.getString(1);
                            data2[1] = rs.getString(2);
                            data2[2] = rs.getString(3);
                            data2[3] = rs.getString(4);
                            data2[4] = rs.getString(5);
                            data2[5] = rs.getString(6);

                            modelo6.addRow(data2);
                            tabla.setModel(modelo6);


                    }
                } else {
                    JOptionPane.showMessageDialog(null, "No existe un producto que coincida con el criterio de búsqueda");

                }
```

Answer (score 0):

Únicamente cambiando el "IF" por un "WHILE", no es suficiente.

Debes sacar del bucle el siguiente código de creación del modelo de tabla:

```
DefaultTableModel modelo6 = new DefaultTableModel();
modelo6.addColumn("ID Inventario");
modelo6.addColumn("Nombre del producto");
modelo6.addColumn("Cantidad");
modelo6.addColumn("Categoría");
modelo6.addColumn("Fecha");
modelo6.addColumn("Precio unitario");
tabla.setModel(modelo6);
```

Si dejas la creación del modelo de tabla dentro del bucle, en cada vuelta te creará de nuevo el modelo, con lo que cada vez "empieza de cero" y por eso solo puede mostrar un resultado, que es el correspondiente a la última pasada que realiza.

Crea el modelo de tabla fuera del bucle y los resultados se irán añadiendo al modelo sin "destruir" los anteriores.

Comment: Muchas gracias por su ayuda!

Answer (score -1):

Debes poner un `while` en vez de una sentencia `if` ya que necesitas recorrer toda la consulta:

```
while (rs.next()) {
    DefaultTableModel modelo6 = new DefaultTableModel();
    modelo6.addColumn("ID Inventario");
    modelo6.addColumn("Nombre del producto");
    modelo6.addColumn("Cantidad");
    modelo6.addColumn("Categoría");
    modelo6.addColumn("Fecha");
    modelo6.addColumn("Precio unitario");
    tabla.setModel(modelo6);

    String data2[] = new String[6];
    data2[0] = rs.getString(1);
    data2[1] = rs.getString(2);
    data2[2] = rs.getString(3);
    data2[3] = rs.getString(4);
    data2[4] = rs.getString(5);
    data2[5] = rs.getString(6);
    modelo6.addRow(data2);
    tabla.setModel(modelo6);
}
```